# Error using .* Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to get matrix of width 17 out from an audio file.
I get Error using  .*  Matrix dimensions must agree. What does it mean and How I am suppose to fix it?

Error is in `windowed_frame = window.*input(((k-1)*bins*overlap)+1:(((k-1))*bins*overlap)+1+bins-1);`

```
[input fs] = wavread('3_1.wav');

fn = fs/2;
bins = 512; %useable bins
frame_length = bins;
window = hamming(frame_length);
overlap = .5;
number_of_frames = (length(input)/(frame_length)/overlap) - 1;

for k=1:number_of_frames

        windowed_frame = window.*input(((k-1)*bins*overlap)+1:(((k-1))*bins*overlap)+1+bins-1);

        fft_window = fft(windowed_frame,bins*2);
        fft_window = abs(fft_window(1:bins));
        fft_energy = fft_window.^2;
        freq_vector = [fn/bins:fn/bins:fn];
```

Edit: Full code
     function test_energy = energy_per_frame(file)

[input fs] = wavread('1_2.wav');

```
fn = fs/2;
bins = 512; %useable bins
frame_length = bins;
window = hamming(frame_length);
overlap = .5;
number_of_frames = (length(input)/(frame_length)/overlap) - 1;

for k=1:number_of_frames

    windowed_frame = (window.*input(((k-1)*bins*overlap)+1:(((k-1))*bins*overlap)+1+bins-1)).';

        fft_window = fft(windowed_frame,bins*2);
        fft_window = abs(fft_window(1:bins));
        fft_energy = fft_window.^2;
        freq_vector = [fn/bins:fn/bins:fn];

        %map bark (z) to bins (1-512) and frequency (freq_vector)
        for i=1:length(freq_vector)
            z(i) = 13*atan(0.76*(freq_vector(i)/1000)) + 3.5*atan(((freq_vector(i)/1000)/7.5).^2);    
        end

        z = floor(z);

        for j=1:length(z);
            if z(j) == 17
                z(j)=16;
            end
        end

        temp = 0;
        temp_sum = 0;
        count = 0;

        %calculate the energy per bark band
        for i=1:length(z)
           if temp == z(i)
               temp_sum = fft_energy(i)+ temp_sum;
               test_energy(k,temp+1) = temp_sum; 
               count = count+1;
           end

           if temp ~= z(i)   
              test_energy(k,temp+1) = temp_sum/count;
              temp = temp+1;
              temp_sum = fft_energy(i);
              count = 1;
           end  
        end  

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.*` operator is element-wise multiplication. In your case it means that each element in `window` is multiplied by the corresponding element in the submatrix `input`, which is the result of the operation:

```
input(((k-1)*bins*overlap)+1:(((k-1))*bins*overlap)+1+bins-1)
```

Obviously both matrices have different dimensions, and you could verify that by typing:

```
size(window)
size(input(((k-1)*bins*overlap)+1:(((k-1))*bins*overlap)+1+bins-1))
```

I suspect that it's a row-column issue: the resulting submatrix `input` is a 1-by-512 *row* vector, whereas `windows` is a 512-by-1 *column* vector.

**The solution:** try adding a dot-apostrophe (`.'`), which is actually the [transpose operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) in MATLAB (as opposed to the `'` operator, the [complex-conjugate](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) transpose, which may not be what you want if your data is complex), at the end of submatrix `input`, like so:

```
windowed_frame = window .* input(blah blah...).'  %// <-- Note the .'
```

I believe that this should correct your problem.

A more generic solution is to force *both* vectors to be column vectors by using the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) (`:`):

```
input_window = input(((k-1)*bins*overlap)+1:(((k-1))*bins*overlap)+1+bins-1);
windowed_frame = window(:) .* input_window(:);
```

Comment: Why dot-apostrophe? I always use apostrophe only for the transpose. What's the difference there?

Comment: Dot-apostrophe (`.'`) is the [transpose operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html), an apostrophe (`'`) is the [complex-conjugate transpose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html). If `input` is guaranteed to be real, there's no difference between the two. However, if it's complex, `'` would produce the wrong result.

Comment: No, It still got the same error. And I find size of window is 512 1,while size(input(((k-1)*bins*overlap)+1:(((k-1))*bins*overlap)+1+bins-1)) is 1 512. edit: I fix it, by usingwindowed_frame = (window.*input(((k-1)*bins*overlap)+1:(((k-1))*bins*overlap)+1+bins-1).';

Comment: But when I change my input to another audio file, it is still got the same error. Original file size was 512 1, while new file is 1 512.

Comment: What is the difference between two solution?

Comment: Yes, it is the same error. After using your solution, the matrix column is showed to be 25. But i only want 17 column. I will post the full code.

Comment: I am such a fool, The matrix are vary depend on input. Thanks for your solution. I am in your debt.

Comment: I would love to, I just don't have enought reputation.